# Dotcloud: running manage.py background service

Tags: django-orm, dotcloud

I have a Django application that needs to access web APIs that are rate-limited by API key.  To manage requests to the API, I've created a simple background server that polls my Django ORM for enqueued task requests, and executes them asynchronously with respect to my app servers (the app servers don't need to block on the results).  The worker server is launched using a custom manage.py command.  The processing requirements of these external lookups are extremely minimal, so I want to run them from my main web service, directly.  I have already rigged it with a makeshift mutex, so that when my application scales, only one of these worker servers will run.

I am trying to figure out the best way to automatically launch this worker server when I deploy my application.  I tried adding it as a command to my supervisord.conf file, but this failed with the error `ImportError: No module named django.core.management`.  I assume this is because supervisord isn't running in the virtual environment in which Django is installed.  So then, I tried running a separate copy of supervisord from the `postinstall` hook.  This is causing my deployment to fail because `postinstall` waits for all commands to complete before terminating, and it is timing out.

Is there a way to fix either of these approaches, or another approach that might work?  It seems to me that I'll run into similar problems even if I do create a separate `python-worker` service.

Comment: Putting in supervisor.conf is the right place for it. Can you put what you entered into supervisor.conf that stopped it from working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track by putting it into `supervisord.conf`. You are also right on why you are getting your error about not finding Django. Luckily this is an easy fix.

You just need to make sure you call your django `manage.py` with the correct python binary (the one inside of the virtualenv), and it should work fine for you.

Here is an example using fully qualified paths to make sure we are using the right files. Your path to manage.py will most likely be different unless your app is also called `myapp`, and you will need to change the `my_awesome_command` to the name of your custom command.

```
[program:custom_command]
directory = /home/dotcloud/current/
command = /home/dotcloud/env/bin/python /home/dotcloud/current/myapp/manage.py my_awesome_command
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_error.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  Follow up question:  do you know what the best way is to send basic signals to the single worker thread?  When activity is low, I have it stop polling the database, to be awakened by a UNIX signal.  But it occurs to me that if I scale out, the other instances will not be able to see the process in order to signal it.  I would rather not run Celery and RabbitMQ just to get the signaling behavior.  I'm thinking about running an Amazon EC2 t1micro instance to host the worker server.  Any suggestions for how I can it on Dotcloud alone?

Comment: @acjohnson55 what will be sending the signals, where will it be coming from, same server, or any server? Another approach outside of Celery and RabbitMQ, would be to use a redis, and just monitor a redis queue, or use something like Amazon SQS. If you want something different you could also look at ZeroMQ. Instead of using a Amazon EC2 instance, why not just run a dotCloud python-worker service?

Comment: I have a large set of recurring tasks that need to run infrequently, and during inactivity, I have the worker stop polling until it knows the next task will be ready.  However, other tasks may need to run immediately in the meantime, so I have the app server send a signal to wake the worker to start polling again.

A worker service may be a good option, but the same issue exists:  is there a good way to have it be triggered, rather than having it poll continually?

Comment: @acjohnson55 if your worker listens to a pub/sub channel then it you can send the signal to the pub/sub channel, and the worker can just listen on that channel for message to come across. It wouldn't have to poll, to know what to do next.

Comment: Liking the sound of that, but what technology can I use to make that work?  Will I have to run Redis or an MQ server?  I'd love to be able to somehow accomplish this in Python, and avoid running/configuring another service/server

Comment: @acjohnson55 redis supports pub/sub so doesn't zeroMQ, you could also check out ZeroRPC, which also supports pub/sub.. Or something hosted like pusher.com, etc.

Comment: ZeroRPC is looking particularly slick, I think I'll give that a try.